# Gromacs: select residues from area

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pymol

I work on lipid and water structure. I have to select every water (group 1) that is below 4A from the lipid (group 2). I used this command:

```
gmx select -f input.gro -s input.tpr -n input.ndx -select 'group 1 and within 0.4 of group 2' -on output.ndx
```

Unfortunately it does the work, but program selects every ATOM in that area, leaving alone H or OH, what I cannot afford for that. I supposed to fix this by adding `-seltype whole_res_com` however the output values were totally nonsense.. Is the other way to select all water residues within 4A of lipid phase?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> gmx select -f input.gro -s input.tpr -n input.ndx -select 'group 1 and
>   same residue as within 0.4 of group 2' -on output.ndx

found out.